# Reading then transmitting a signal over BLE for Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to read a signal from a magnetic sensor then want to send it over BLE to a Raspberry Pi 3 module.

What device(s) can I use for the BLE signal reading / transmitting and how do I pair it with a Raspberry Pi 3? Did anyone else try doing this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lots of modules that you can use for transmitting over bluetooth, [SimModules](http://simcom.ee/modules/gsm-gprs-gnss/sim808/) and [Hc](http://www.instructables.com/id/AT-command-mode-of-HC-05-Bluetooth-module/) Modules are two of them. Sim modules also support GPRS and 2G networks. both of them works with At Commands and it can be controlled by a simple MicroController like Arduino series.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do I need to connect these to an Arduino or a Raspberry Pi to make them work? I'd like to find a standalone, programmable module (kind of like a Beacon) that sends a signal over BLE to the Arduino device.

Comment: it depends on your raspberry version. Raspberry 3 has bluetooth hardware by itself , remember to use latest raspbian Os for hardware support.